# VBA syntax to reference cell on same row inside conditional format

Tags: vba, date, syntax, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a VBA Macro to automate part of a large process.  I can do it manually but it isn't practical as there are 27K rows.

I have a range of dates in columns F through AC.  I'm trying to use conditional formatting to color the ones that fall between the dates in columns A and B on the same row.  IE:  Row 2 (1 is headers) A2 and B2 are dates that span one year.  F2:AC2 are filled with dates that may or may not fall in that range.  Turn the ones that do red (pink red text or what ever).  Continue for the next 27K rows.

What I have is working on a 57 item sample Except that it only references the original hard coded selections from the macro recording.  I'm struggling with the syntax to make it dynamic.

```
[code]Sub Conditions()
```

'
    ' Conditional format
'

```
    Dim x As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    NumRows = Range("F2", Range("F2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    'Range("F2").Select
    'Range(("F2"), Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select


    Range("F2").Select
    Range(("F2"), Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select 

For x = 1 To NumRows
        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="=$A$2", Formula2:="=$B$2"
        'Formula1:="=ActiveCell.Offset(0,-5)", Formula2:="=ActiveCell.Offset(0,-4)" '<---- offset from active cell

    Selection.FormatConditions    (Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub [code]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Change Formula1:="=$A$2", Formula2:="=$B$2", to Formula1:="=$A2", Formula2:="=$B2", so that the rows are relative.  Can't you just use numrows to get a range to select?  Range("F2:AC" & numrows).select, then apply your conditions to the the entire range.

Comment: I wound up doing this.  the "$" changes weren't working consistently but that was tied to data format issues I think.  Oh.. and something else had it only selecting some cells.  Not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

this worked perfectly.

```
Sub Conditions2()

    Dim numrows As Long

    Range("F2").Select

    numrows = Range("F2", Range("F2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    With Range("F2", Range("F2").End(xlToRight)).Resize(numrows)
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=$A2", Formula2:="=$B2")
            .SetFirstPriority
            With .Font
                .Color = -16383844
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            With .Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 13551615
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Get rid of  Range("F2").Select it serves no purpose here and be aware you are implicitly referencing the activesheet. You might want to explicitly reference the sheet by its name.